# Using jquery dialog in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I am currently running my web application in JSF 2.0 and jquery. Moreover i have added jquery dialog. Model dialog is opening properly without any errors. However when i try to submit by ajax input vales on the dialog are not posting to server side.

Please refer below input text and button to submit the values.

#### Input:

```
<h:inputText id="routingNumber_1" required="true" class="routingNo"
    value="#{paymentInfoController.modelBankInfo.routingNumber}"
    valueChangeListener="#{paymentInfoController.getBankByRoutingNumber}">
</h:inputText>
```

#### Button:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="fll btn2 btnOff mr savepannextbutton" 
    id="savepannextbutton" style=" align:left;height: 40px; width: 70px;"
    value="Confirm" title="Confirm">
    <f:attribute name="bank" 
        value="#{paymentInfoController.modelBankInfo.routingNumber}">
    </f:attribute>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="addBankshowSuccessMessage" event="click"
        render=":formPaymentInformation:paymentInformationDataTable"
        listener="#{paymentInfoController.addBank}">
    </f:ajax>
</h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

A JS/CSS modal dialog is by design usually repositioned to end of body (to prevent possible browser specific layout/presentation/zindex problems). So, if you have placed the HTML element representing the dialog inside a `<h:form>`, then the dialog will end up being placed outside any HTML `<form>` and thus not being able to submit anything to the server.

You need to ensure that the `<h:form>` is been placed inside the dialog.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, consider looking at a JSF component library which is using jQuery UI under the covers instead of homebrewing/reinventing all the JSF+jQuery matters. [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org), for example, has a [`<p:dialog>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf) as all-in-one solution for this purpose.